# wp_update_user not updating

Tags: user-roles, user-access, user-meta

In desperation I am asking for help in this forum too - if someone (ANYONE!) could take a look a this post and see if they could help I'd be eternally grateful

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_update_user-not-updating?replies=11

Basically - I am updating a user's role and capabilities via script but the changes only come in to effect (ie the user can see specific menu items) when I go into that user and hit "save"

Thanks in anticipation!!

Chris

**UPDATE:**

Maybe this helps solve it?

**This is the WP_User object I have echoed out on screen when logged in as the newly changed user**:

```
WP_User Object ( [data] => stdClass Object ( [ID] => 130 [user_login] => test [user_pass] => $P$BuHO1ABLCNQ716tktgyes4jqqkfVxG. [user_nicename] => test [user_email] => email@gmail.com [user_url] => [user_registered] => 2012-07-19 12:07:52 [user_activation_key] => [user_status] => 0 [display_name] => test ) [ID] => 130 [caps] => Array ( [editor] => 1 ) [cap_key] => wp_capabilities [roles] => Array ( [0] => editor ) [allcaps] => Array ( [upload_files] => 1 [unfiltered_html] => 1 [edit_posts] => 1 [edit_published_posts] => 1 [publish_posts] => 1 [edit_pages] => 1 [read] => 1 [level_7] => 1 [level_6] => 1 [level_5] => 1 [level_4] => 1 [level_3] => 1 [level_2] => 1 [level_1] => 1 [level_0] => 1 [edit_published_pages] => 1 [publish_pages] => 1 [manage_options] => 1 [view_menu] => 1 [editor] => 1 ) [filter] => )
```

**This is how the menu item is being created in my plugin file (which should display to the user):**

```
add_menu_page('Welcome', 'Welcome','edit_posts', 'welcome', 'welcome_page', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/images/icon.png', 0);
```

**This is the function / page  that the menu item returns:**

```
function welcome_page()
 {
    global $currrent_user;
if(!current_user_can('edit_posts'))
{

    print '<div class="wrap"><h2>Your account has been restricted, most likely due to an unpaid subscription.</div>';
}
else
{
    include 'welcome-page.php';
}
 }
```

As you can see - the user only needs edit_posts capability to view the menu item and for the function to return the welcome page. The user indeed has this capability, but cant do either of these things - unless i click "save" as admin in the user-edit page??

**Edit 2**

**The following are all the different approaches I have taken to change the user role - if it helps!**

```
//using this currently
$user = new WP_User($unpaid->uid);//$unpaid->uid is the users ID
$user->set_role('editor');
if(!$user->has_cap('edit_posts'))
{
$user->add_cap('edit_posts');
}
wp_cache_delete($unpaid->uid, 'users');

//another attempt
$uID = $unpaid->uid;
wp_insert_user(array('ID'=>$uID,'role'=>'editor'));
```

**UPDATE AGAIN!**

I have just tried this and again, the db is updated, even shows 'editor' in the admin panel, but the user still cant see the appropriate menu items unless I click "update" on their profile!

```
$new = new WP_User($current_user->ID);
$new->set_role('editor');

wp_cache_delete( $new->ID, 'users' );
wp_cache_delete( $new->user_login, 'userlogins' );
wp_cache_delete( $new->user_email, 'useremail' );
wp_cache_delete( $new->user_nicename, 'userslugs' );
do_action('profile_update');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I have tried everything I know of here guys - any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using another plugin such as User Role Editor by any chance? I'm looking at doing something similar to you but haven't got round to it yet. My early investigations have left me with a note to look into the wp_capabilities values. It's been a while so I can't remember why but, I've added this code snipped to my notes which could help you? `update_user_meta($user_id, 'wp_capabilities', '');`

Comment: If the user flushes browser cache does this show the menu? Also if supercache etc are disabled, or both, does this help?

Comment: Also does changing the capability required on the menu to the editor role rather than edit_posts help?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with a normal wp_user_update of the display_name. I disabled my caching solutions and nothing changes. If I go to the profile page of the user, the display name is updated, but the website shows it only after I hit the Update button in user-edit.php

Comment: I tried also to delete the browser cache, no way.

Comment: @StefanoTombolini I'm sure it would be helpful to others if you provided  a code snippet that makes the problem easier to verify.

Comment: @birgire Actually I have no real clue, I'm just using wp_user_update in the functions.php of my theme.

Comment: @birgire This question is 6 years old... I might suggest posting a new question, even with a bounty if you want. And if you do, please provide us with the code you're currently using so that we can try to spot the problem.

Comment: @birgire Though, off the top of my head, make sure you're using wp_update_user() and not wp_user_update() which isn't actually a function... [Check the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/)

Comment: @Myles I'm not the one adding the bounty ;-) Looks like you wanted to address Stefano Tombolini.

Comment: @birgire haha you're right. Sorry about that

Comment: @StefanoTombolini see above

Answer (score 4):

Im using `remove_role` and then `add_role` to upgrade a user from one role to another.

Here is a function that checks all user within the user role **subscriber** and upgrade them to **editor** every hour.

```
/**
* Add a cron job that will update
* Subscribers to editors. Runs hourly
*/


add_action('check_user_role', 'upgrade_user');

function run_check_user_role() {
    if ( !wp_next_scheduled( 'check_user_role' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( current_time( 'timestamp' ), 'hourly', 'check_user_role');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'run_check_user_role' );



function upgrade_user() {

    // Get users in subscriber role
    $args = array(
        'role'  =>  'subscriber',
    );

    $users = get_users( $args );

    foreach ( $users as $user ) {

        $user = new WP_User( $user->ID );

        // Remove current subscriber role
        $user->remove_role( 'subscriber' );

        // Upgrade to editor role
        $user->add_role( 'editor' );

    }
}
```

Here is a way so you can try to upgrade the users manually:

**Run this as http://yourdomain.com/?upgrade_user**

```
if ( isset( $_REQUEST['upgrade_user'] ) ) {
    upgrade_user();
}
```

Comment: Tried that one Pontus - no good im afraid - my mind is slowly turning to mush - this is the one tiny fly in an otherwise cracking system!

Comment: Thats weird, im running this on a newly created WordPress 3.4 install and it works for me. Where do you add it? and do you have something like this function already?

Comment: You can see my update above - I run the code in my plugin file. The database updates correctly - but the user still cant see the menu items, unless I log in as admin, go to users > edit the user and simply click "save"...

Comment: You should add global $current_user to check the capabilities of the user, i have updated your code. you can check on a role instead like this: `if ( $user->has_cap('edit_posts') ) {}`

Comment: Sorry Pontus - you've updated my code? I have included another edit to my initial post - I have tried has_cap. Am I wrong in assuming I don't need to declare global $current_user if I already have the user's ID?

Comment: You can't use current_user_can without globalize the $current_user within the function.

Comment: Ahh - see! god I hope this works - back shortly!

Comment: alas my friend - no change :( I have edited the code up the top to reflect in case I did something wrong..

Answer (score 1):

I better method is.
Which uses WP_User to toggle/set the role.

```
$role = 'editor';
$user = new WP_User($user_id);
$user->set_role($role);
```

Comment: Since this has been -3'ed, can someone advise why my solution is wrong?

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys - have tried both these approaches but to no avail :( I believe the system is updating the database correctly but the user still can't access the applicable menu items until I go into that user and click save...?

Comment: Try adding `wp_cache_delete($user_id, 'users');` after my $user->set_role. But before doing that. Does the user get shown the correct menu items, if they logout and in again? If so the WP temp cache is interfering and wp_cache_delete will clear this. (Have not tested)

Comment: Thanks Barry - they still cant see the menu items after logout and log back in again. - it's like the updating function is missing or not doing one small something that occurs when updating a user profile via the admin > users panel...?

Comment: I don't suppose you are running any additional plugins that are caching, such as w3 total cache, or super cache?

Comment: nup - would it have anything to do with a transient do you think? I feel that we are so close - there must be something the happens when you save a user profile in user-edit.php that my script isnt doing...

Comment: This answer is correct, I tested it, it works properly. I don't know what you're doing wrong, but there is literally nothing more to setting new roles than this.

Comment: OK thanks @Otto -I'll re-look over everything :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use other plugins you need to read the documentation on how to set role.
In my case, I used Ultimate Member so I have to add these lines:

```php
UM()->roles()->set_role( $user_id, $user_role );
//and then clear the user cache after updating the role:
UM()->user()->remove_cache( $user_id );
```

Comment: This worked for me. As suggested by Son, we also need to check the plugin which handles access control for the menu display. In my case, it was Ultimate Member plugin and the above code worked perfectly.